# Outputting Unity commandline build log to console?

Tags: unity, build-process, jenkins

I'm using Blue Ocean to do a Unity3D build through command lines (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html).

I currently have a stage in blue ocean which runs the build command in a 'Windows Batch Script' outputting the log to a text file on the computer.

is there a way to also output that same logging text to the blue ocean build output? Right now all I see is the batch command.

One way to accomplish this would be if the build output was sent to the console instead of just the logfile passed in the argument.